# Bootstrap 4-beta navbar-inverse and navbar-fixed-bottom not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set a navbar and a footer using Bootstrap 4-beta in ASP.NETCore web application but the navbar of Bootstrap not working properly I used navbar-inverse and navbar-dark but problem is same and I also trying set a footer using navbar and navbar-fixed-bottom but the footer not going bottom of the page. I'm new to Bootstrap and ASP.NET MVC.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="display:flex; justify-content:flex-end; align-items:center;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <button id="sidebarToggle" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a asp-controller="App" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand mr-auto" style="color:cornflowerblue">
            The World
            </a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save
                    </a>
                </li>
                </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                        <i class="fa fa-print"></i>Print
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
        <div>
            @RenderBody() 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" class="container-fluid">
        <footer>
            <div  class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
                <h4 class="text-center text-primary">Copyright &copy; 2017</h4>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:
[image: Result:]
What I'm doing wrong? Thanks !

Comment: can you please put your code using snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because In Bootstrap 4 They changed **.navbar-fixed-bottom** to **.fixed-bottom**